# Looking for an Angular2 MEAN Stack

Tags: node.js, bower, mean-stack, angular

I am trying to use Angular2 with a NodeJS backend.
I don't actually need the whole MEAN stack but only a few things :
- Angular2
- Bower
- NodeJS
- gulp or grunt to make these work all together

I found an article on android2-education but the version of angular used is so old that it simply does not work anymore. Same thing with yeoman generators :(

I have searched the web looking for this and I am surprised I can't find a proper tutorial or starter kit.

Comment: Have you seen this project? https://github.com/pkozlowski-opensource/ng2-play.ts

Comment: I use Systemjs in my angular 2 app. However, I am looking for a full client/server starter kit which includes nodejs backend (using express preferably) and angular2 for the frontend (using bower to install)

Comment: You should have a look at [angular2-seed](https://github.com/mgechev/angular2-seed) - disclaimer: I'm an active contrib

Answer (score 6):

I was looking for the same thing and found a tutorial going in-depth about how to set it up here: http://thejackalofjavascript.com/developing-a-mean-app-with-angular-2-0/

The author uses the following that fits your request:

- MongoDB
- Express
- Angular 2.0 2.0.0-alpha (but any version can be used)
- Node.js

I am very happy he uses Gulp instead of Grunt. It would have been even better if Webpack was used but we can't get everything we want, can we!

Comment: Angular2 quick start application with Repository pattern and updated to RC5 https://github.com/moizKachwala/Angular2-expressjs-mongoose-gulp-node-typescript